# FL Studio: How to register the actual keyboard sound?

Tags: sound-design, audio-recording, keyboard, fl-studio, instruments

**THE SITUATION:**

I have succesfully connected the keyboard to FL Studio 12.

If I select a a drum or whatever other sound inside FL Studio i can play it using the keyboard. That's cool.

But I also would like to register and use the actual keyboard sound along with its own presets.

The keyboard Casio CTK-3400SK (though i don't think it really matter the type)

**THE QUESTION:**

How i can record the actual sound of a digital keyboard into FL Studio 12?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

**Explanation**

You'll want to run a 1/4" (jack) cable out of your keyboards audio (main) out and plug it into your audio interface. Then in FL Studio you'll have to open the mixer and select an empty channel. On the top right of the mixer above the effect slots you can select an audio input. Select your audio interface from the dropdown and you should get the audio directly from you keyboard.

**Edit**

As you asked, FL Studio 12 has the option to directly record the audio to a .wav file. You could also use an audio recording plugin if you want to edit the recorded sound.

**Picture**

[image: Audio interface selection]

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how the ins and outs of FL works as I am a logic user, but generally speaking you will want to run a 1/4" cable out of your keyboard's audio output and into your audio interface. Then create a new audio track within FL and set your input to where you plugged in the keyboard

Optional: if you want to have MIDI capabilities you can use a MIDI cable with your interface. Plug it this way

Interface Midi OUT -> Keyboard Midi IN

Interface Midi In -> Keyboard Midi Out

Then you will use an external instrument to trigger the keyboard.

To Record, make sure you freeze the tracks/presets

Comment: I am not able yet. I open a new project. Delete all the tracks presets. And i don't hear anything.